# Umbraco 8 - Error in all.generated.cs when I add Macro inside RTE

Tags: c#, .net, macros, umbraco

When I try to add any kind of Macro (Even if it just includes an empty `<Div>`) into a RTE, it throws the next error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from '***' on 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedModels.***'. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: doc
   at Umbraco.Web.Macros.PublishedContentHashtableConverter..ctor(IPublishedContent doc) in D:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Web\Macros\PublishedContentHashtableConverter.cs:line 57
   at Umbraco.Web.Macros.MacroRenderer.Render(String macroAlias, IPublishedContent content, IDictionary`2 macroParams) in D:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Web\Macros\MacroRenderer.cs:line 200
   at Umbraco.Web.PropertyEditors.ValueConverters.RteMacroRenderingValueConverter.<>c__DisplayClass4_1.<RenderRteMacros>b__1(String macroAlias, Dictionary`2 macroAttributes) in D:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Web\PropertyEditors\ValueConverters\RteMacroRenderingValueConverter.cs:line 57
   at Umbraco.Web.Macros.MacroTagParser.ParseMacros(String text, Action`1 textFoundCallback, Action`2 macroFoundCallback) in D:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Web\Macros\MacroTagParser.cs:line 196
   at Umbraco.Web.PropertyEditors.ValueConverters.RteMacroRenderingValueConverter.RenderRteMacros(String source, Boolean preview) in D:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Web\PropertyEditors\ValueConverters\RteMacroRenderingValueConverter.cs:line 63
   at Umbraco.Web.PropertyEditors.ValueConverters.RteMacroRenderingValueConverter.Convert(Object source, Boolean preview) in D:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Web\PropertyEditors\ValueConverters\RteMacroRenderingValueConverter.cs:line 89
   at Umbraco.Web.PropertyEditors.ValueConverters.RteMacroRenderingValueConverter.ConvertIntermediateToObject(IPublishedElement owner, IPublishedPropertyType propertyType, PropertyCacheLevel referenceCacheLevel, Object inter, Boolean preview) in D:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Web\PropertyEditors\ValueConverters\RteMacroRenderingValueConverter.cs:line 71
   at Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent.PublishedPropertyType.ConvertInterToObject(IPublishedElement owner, PropertyCacheLevel referenceCacheLevel, Object inter, Boolean preview) in D:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Core\Models\PublishedContent\PublishedPropertyType.cs:line 219
   at Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.NuCache.Property.GetValue(String culture, String segment) in D:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Web\PublishedCache\NuCache\Property.cs:line 211
   at Umbraco.Web.PublishedPropertyExtension.Value[T](IPublishedProperty property, String culture, String segment, Fallback fallback, T defaultValue) in D:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Web\PublishedPropertyExtension.cs:line 39
   at Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentExtensions.Value[T](IPublishedContent content, String alias, String culture, String segment, Fallback fallback, T defaultValue) in D:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Web\PublishedContentExtensions.cs:line 163
   at Umbraco.Web.PublishedModels.*** in ***\App_Data\Models\all.generated.cs:line 748
   at ***
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target) in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DynamicValueProvider.cs:line 110
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target) in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DynamicValueProvider.cs:line 114
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue) in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line 520
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty) in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line 469
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType) in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line 95
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType) in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializer.cs:line 1151
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer) in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs:line 664
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings) in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs:line 629
```

Some names and paths are censored.

While debugging my code it shows the next error when trying to serialize `IPublishedContent` in `all.generated.cs`:
[image: Error in all.generated.cs]

I don't use Umbraco templates, the client side is separated and retrieves data from Umbraco using HTTP requests to a custom API endpoint that uses `UmbracoHelper`.
I'm not using MVC.

Has someone faced that issue and knows how to handle that?